# Not receiving any notifications on implementing NotifiationListenerService

Tags: java, android

I am implementing an application to read notifications and display them on my application . There's no error being highlighted but nothing is getting displayed either. I have enabled the notification access to my application too on the phone.

My MainActivity.java is :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TableLayout tab;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tab = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tab);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(onNotice, new IntentFilter("Msg"));
    }
    private BroadcastReceiver onNotice= new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String pack = intent.getStringExtra("package");
            String title = intent.getStringExtra("title");
            String text = intent.getStringExtra("text");

            TableRow tr = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
            tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams( TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            TextView textview = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            textview.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1.0f));
            textview.setTextSize(20);
            textview.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0B0719"));
            textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(pack +"<br><b>" + title + " : </b>" + text));
            tr.addView(textview);
            tab.addView(tr);
        }
    };
}
```

The NotifiationService.java is:

```
public class NotificationService extends NotificationListenerService {
    Context context;

    @Override

    public void onCreate() {

        super.onCreate();
        context = getApplicationContext();

    }
    @Override

    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {


        String pack = sbn.getPackageName();
        String ticker = sbn.getNotification().tickerText.toString();
        Bundle extras = sbn.getNotification().extras;
        String title = extras.getString("android.title");
        String text = extras.getCharSequence("android.text").toString();

        Log.i("Package",pack);
        Log.i("Ticker",ticker);
        Log.i("Title",title);
        Log.i("Text",text);

        Intent msgrcv = new Intent("Msg");
        msgrcv.putExtra("package", pack);
        msgrcv.putExtra("ticker", ticker);
        msgrcv.putExtra("title", title);
        msgrcv.putExtra("text", text);

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(msgrcv);


    }

    @Override

    public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        Log.i("Msg","Notification Removed");

    }
}
```

The AndroidManifest.xml is :

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name="com.example.vk9621.notification1.NotificationService"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">

            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />

            </intent-filter>

        </service>
    </application>
```

The ActivityMain.xml is:

```
 <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tab" />
    </ScrollView>
```

Can someone highlight what mistake I am making that leads to no notification on the screen of the application?

Comment: Have you enabled Notification access for your app in the device Settings?

Comment: Yes.. I have done so.@MikeM.

Comment: Got it resolved.. Had to increase the minimum API level.